# QuickBlox notifications not working for Android

Tags: android, push-notification, quickblox-android

I've been using QuickBlox sample-pushnotifications ([link](https://github.com/QuickBlox/quickblox-android-sdk/tree/4615f2961c7a720f00bfe3d0bdd1f8759348cdc0/sample-pushnotifications)) and it's not working - both with test data from sample and mine. Steps are following:

- Setup keys in Application
- createSession with user credentials
- createSubscription (I added this by myself - it's working and my user is present in dashboard)
- register receiver (from sample and custom)
- The app is running, time to send a message.
- createEvent.

All of QB operations are successful (by that I mean "all onSuccess methods are invoked"), but I don't receive any notifications at all. Receiver's onReceive method is not invoked. I have also tried to send them via dashboard. They appear in Push Notifications->Queue with status "sent", but still - no action on device side.

Comment: Yes, it's happening for us also. In Quickblox dashboard, we will get the message, "Sent", but it's never received by the client.

Comment: Did you solve the issue. I am facing same issue

Comment: are u solve this ? im stuck now with this